# How to check for URL re-write rule at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, url-rewriting

Is there a way to check to see if a URL re-write rule exists on the web server at runtime?

I tried playing with

`System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();`

but I get an error stating Configuration does not exist in System.Configuration.

Background: Mads Kristensen showed how to create cache-busting URL rewrites (when adding expirations for static content) at TechEd, but my company does not allow for me to add the rules in my web.config so I am having to get the sys admin to add the rule using IIS Manager. The problem with that is, now I don't have those rules on my local machine so when I am running the site locally the static content doesn't load. If I can check to see if the rule exists at runtime then I can just skip the "fingerprinting" which gives my static content a unique URL and forgo the re-write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For global IIS rules stored in applicationHost.config (and redirection.config):

The config is located at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and you need to use ServerManager class from Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace (you need to reference to the System.Web.Administration.dll located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv)

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
     Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration(); // or set application name 

     ConfigurationSection rulesSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/rewrite/rules");
     ConfigurationElementCollection rulesCollection = rulesSection.GetCollection();

     foreach (var r in rulesCollection)
     {
         foreach (var c in r.ChildElements)
         {
            foreach (var a in c.Attributes)
                Response.Write(a.Name + "=" + a.Value);
         }
     }
}
```

By default, your application identity used for the application pool might not have enough rights to read that folder and you either need run the pool under a powerful account or ask your admin to assign current account to read configuration files.

For rules stored in a web.config:

In IIS7 rewrite section is a part of system.webServer

```
Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath); 
ConfigurationSection cs = webConfig.GetSection("system.webServer");
if (cs != null)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(cs.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()));
    IEnumerable<XElement> rules = from c in xml.Descendants("rule") select c;

    foreach (XElement rule in rules)
    {
        Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(rule.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That only works if the rule was added in the web.config. I want to check if the rule was added as an "Inbound Rule" through IIS Manager. Thanks though.

Comment: As you stated, I was denied access. If you don't mind, I'd ask you append your original response to read the web.config rewrite rules, just in case it might help someone else. Thanks for your help.